# How should I build manylinux project docker image?

Tags: windows, docker, python-manylinux

Hi I need a manylinux1 whl distribute for some python package to work in an old server.

I found the [manylinux](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux) project and installed docker.

My platform is Windows 10 and processor is Intel, so I cannot run nest virtualization in VirtualBox.

So how should I build the docker image under Windows?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Manylinux helps to compile for different CPU architectures. It also helps to repair your wheel for a manylinux tag and makes it acceptable by PyPI.
If you're building wheels, consider porting your project to a CI environemnt, like GitHub Actions, and use CIBUILDWHEEL. It helps when you have to compile for many platforms and Python versions.